# showing background image using emotion css

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I am trying to show a background image on an input element using emotion css. But so far I am unsuccesful to do so.
This is what I tried
I imported emotion css and the image

```
    import styled from "@emotion/styled"
    import IconError from "../images/icon-error.svg";
```

I defined the styled input element

```
  const Input = styled.input(
   {
     background: `url(${IconError})`
   }
 )
```

Finally I used the input element inside a form

```
    return (
      <Form className="email-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input id="email" type="text" name="email"
        placeholder="Email Address" aria-label="Email input"/>
        <Button className="submit" type="submit" aria-label="Submit button">
        </Button>
       </Form>
    );
```

I see all the other styling but no background image.

Comment: One more piece of information I can show the image outside the input tag by using ```<IconError/>``` So the path to the image is good

Comment: Everything looks alright in [this example I tested it out with](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pine-hrxkl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), was there a console error on the page render? and what was the status code for the image network request, any errors there?

Comment: Thanks Emma. It gets me closer. There are no errors in the console. I did notice that I get it to work with ```const logo = "https://duckduckgo.com/assets/logo_header.v108.svg"``` but when I download the image to my images folder and try ```import logo from "../images/logo_header.v108.svg"``` it does not work. I am very puzzled by this.

Comment: Hmm that looks like it could be a webpack config issue, in the network tab, can you see the request for the svg file there? is it a 200 or some other code?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar issue where I was trying to get an image as the background for a specific div. However, the first section of code would give me an error.

```
export const FilterHeaderDiv = styled.div`
  background-image: url('../../../data/images/charts-header.png');

`
```

The error that it gave me in the console was the following...

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I solved it by importing the image and adding it to the URL as a variable.

```
import chartsHeaderImage from "../../../data/images/charts-header.png";
export const FilterHeaderDiv = styled.div`
      background-image: url(${chartsHeaderImage});

    `
```

I did not find any resources covering this so just thought I would add this here if anyone would need this.